# Find real frame of UIVIew

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a custom `UIView` I create in my class. I then add it to my screen and I want to know it's `CGRect`. But from what it seems, I can't seem to get the size of this particular `UIView`. Here's my code:

```
CGRect labelFrame;
        if (!tickerImage) {
            labelFrame = CGRectMake(upperTextField.frame.origin.x + 8, upperTextField.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
        } else {
            labelFrame = CGRectMake(upperTextField.frame.origin.x + 16, upperTextField.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
        }

        SGNewLabel = [[SGAdressLabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [labelsArray addObject:SGNewLabel];
        [self.view addSubview:SGNewLabel];

        [SGNewLabel addNewLabelWithText:labelText andTickerImage:tickerImage];

        UIView *lastLabel = [labelsArray lastObject];
        CGRect newTextFieldFrame = CGRectMake(lastLabel.frame.origin.x + lastLabel.frame.size.width, labelFrame.origin.y, 320, 30);
        upperTextField.frame = newTextFieldFrame;
```

As you see, I set the `upperTextField` frame based on the frame of my custom `SGNewLabel` which appears to be wrong, even if put into `NSArray`. I set `0, 0` at the end of the `labelFrame` declaration because I don't know the size of the future object and here is the source of my problem.

How can I correct it and get the right size of my UIView?

**EDIT**:
NSLog on my view gives me this:

```
NSLog(@"The rect of object is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
2013-02-11 17:16:02.333 MyApp[2383:c07] The rect of object is: {{24, 55}, {0, 0}}
```

The `UIView` itself is drawn normally and I can see it full-sized.

Comment: have u tried `yourView.frame`?

Comment: @rptwsthi That's what I'm doing in the `lastLabel.frame`, it gives me the same result with `lastLabel` or with `SGNewLabel`

Comment: As log says you need to customize the frame of the view

Comment: @rptwsthi But how do I do that if I don't know its length or height? It should be flexible

Comment: set it after getting cumulative dimensions of it's subViews. When all values of subviews are already set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used my label's frame set in its own class and then my code would look like this:

```
SGNewLabel = [[SGAdressLabel alloc] init];
CGRect labelFrame;
        if (!tickerImage) {
            labelFrame = CGRectMake(upperTextField.frame.origin.x + 8, upperTextField.frame.origin.y, SGNewLabel.frame.size.width, SGNewLabel.frame.size.height);
        } else {
            labelFrame = CGRectMake(upperTextField.frame.origin.x + 16, upperTextField.frame.origin.y, SGNewLabel.frame.size.width, SGNewLabel.frame.size.height);
        }
SGNewLabel.frame = labelFrame;
```